# static files doesn't load on cache clear?

Tags: python, django

I have a Django project when I set Debug=true and cache clear when running the static files will not load. If I set it to false the page will load with static files. Any solution to this problem

Comment: Please iclude more info about how you run your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For managing static files you must use

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Then give yes. I hope your static files are in static directory. It has nothing to do with DEBUG in settings.py because it just renders the error message when set to True.

Comment: thanks it worked...